# Let $a$ and $b$ commute. If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then ord($ab$) = $mn$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is exercise $10.E.4$ from Pinter:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$.
>
> Let ord($a$) = $m$ and ord($b$) = $n$.
>
> Prove:
>
> Let $a$ and $b$ commute.
>
> If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then ord($ab$) = $mn$.
>
> (HINT: Use $10.E.2$.)

Here is $10.E.2$, which Pinter suggests that we use:

> If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then no power of $a$ can be equal to any power of $b$ (except for $e$).

I'm also going to use $10.E.1$:

> If $a$ and $b$ commute, then ord($ab$) is a divisor of lcm($m$,$n$).

As well as $B.T6.i$ (Theorem $6.i$ from Appendix $B$. A fact from basic number theory.):

> If   gcd($m$,$n$) = 1   then   lcm($m$,$n$) = $mn$

Let's begin.

We are given that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime which means that:

$$\text{gcd}(m,n) = 1$$

By $B.T6.i$:

$$  \text{lcm}(m,n) = mn \tag{1}  $$

By $10.E.1$:

$$ \text{ord}(ab)\ |\ \text{lcm}(m,n) $$

Substituting $(1)$:

$$ \text{ord}(ab)\ |\ mn $$

Which means that there is an integer $x$ such that:

$$ \text{ord}(ab) x = mn $$

This is so close! For the theorem to be true, we'd have to show that $x = 1$.

However, the original exercise statement says to use $10.E.2$.

- Is that helpful in showing that $x = 1$?
- Or is there some other completely different approach whereby $10.E.2$ is used?

---

**UPDATE**: Some comments regarding the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3304350/23010) below.

The proof uses the following fact:

> If $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $lcm(a,b)|c$.

For this exercise, I wanted to only use theorems that had been presented in the book up to that point. And, I didn't seem to recall seeing this theorem. (If anyone spots this in Pinter, please comment below with the location.)

However, I did notice that the following similar fact is in Appendix B (REVIEW OF THE INTEGERS) as exercise B.9:

> If $a|c$ and $b|c$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$ then $ab|c$.

So yeah, it looks like the approach shown below is definitely a valid way to go if you want to stick to what's presented in the book.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $a$ and $b$ commute and $\text{gcd}\left(\text{ord}(a),\text{ord}(b)\right)=1$, then $\text{ord}(ab)=\text{ord}(a)\text{ord}(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370004/if-a-and-b-commute-and-textgcd-left-textorda-textordb-right-1?rq=1).

Comment: The 2nd $\Rightarrow$ in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803289/242) in the dupe is essentially a proof of 10.E.2, so replace that by an invocation of 10.E.2 to obtain the hinted proof. This is a well-known proof and likely occurs here many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### $$\boxed{\textit{You can show $mn\ \big|\ \text{ord}(ab)$ using $10.E.2$:}}$$

Since $a$ and $b$ commute we can distribute common powers of $a$ and $b$:
$$
e = (ab)^{\text{ord}(ab)} = a^{\text{ord}(ab)}b^{\text{ord}(ab)}
$$ This implies $a^{\text{ord}(ab)} = b^{-\text{ord}(ab)}$ or, in other words, some power of $a$ equals some power of $b$. But $10.E.2$ says that since $m = \text{ord}(a)$ and $n = \text{ord}(b)$ are relatively prime, no power of $a$ can equal any power of $b$ unless those powers of $a$ and $b$ both evaluate to $e$.

So we must have $a^{\text{ord}(ab)} = e = a^m$ and $b^{-\text{ord}(ab)} = e = b^n$.

But then, $m\ \big|\ \text{ord}(ab)$. This is because $m$ is the order of $a$ i.e. the least positive integer power of $a$ that evaluates to $e$; ***so if any other positive integer power of $a$ evaluates to $e$ (like $\text{ord}(ab)$ here), then $m$ must divide that integer***. For a similar reason, $n\ \big|\ \text{ord}(ab)$.

Therefore since both $m$ and $n$ divide $\text{ord}(ab)$, ***their least common multiple $\text{lcm}(m,n)$ must divide $\text{ord}(ab)$***. But in our case $\text{lcm}(m,n) = mn$ so we finally have $mn\ \big|\ \text{ord}(ab)$.

Along with the result you already established $\text{ord}(ab)\ \big|\ mn$, this suggests $\text{ord}(ab) = mn$.

***P.S.*** *If you don't believe the bolded statements above, use Euclidean Division. E.g. to see $m\ \big|\ \text{ord}(ab)$, use Euclidean Division on the integer pair $\big(m, \text{ord}(ab)\big)$ to get $\text{ord}(ab) = km + r$ for some $k, r \in \Bbb Z$ with $0 \leq r < m$. Do you see why $r$ must be $0$?*

Comment: Excellent and very clear presentation! I learned a few things from your proof. Thanks very much for explaining each part. I've updated my answer with some comments regarding your approach.

Comment: can we do this question this way : is to consider various powers of $a^ib^j$. where $1 < i \leq m..1<j \leq n$ all of these are distinct and $a^mb^n=e$. so order of $ab$ is  $\geq mn$...

Comment: is their any proof of this : m=ord(a)
 and n=ord(b)
 are relatively prime, no power of a
 can equal any power of b
 unless those powers of a
 and b
 both evaluate to e

Comment: @SophieClad You can post the questions on the site; comment sections are too small for answers

Comment: @ayeayemaung i have already asked

Comment: @ayeayemaungthey closed question and linked it to this question

Comment: @SophieClad that's because my answer does indeed answer your first question. $O(ab) = mn$ as I showed. But you never posted your second comment as a question.

Comment: @ayeayemaung : i just want to know if thsi is true :  is to consider various powers of aibj
. where 1<i≤m..1<j≤n
 all of these are distinct and ambn=e
. so order of ab
 is ≥mn